# ansible become_user for a set of tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Currently for a given task `ansible-2.x` provides an option called `become_user` that allows changing the user before the task in context is run. For example:

```
- name: Run Django database migrations
  django_manage:
    command: migrate
    app_path: "{{ project_path }}"
    settings: "{{ django_settings_file }}"
  become_user: "{{ project_user }}"
```

The `become_user` here only applies to the task in context and does not apply to all subsequent tasks that are run after this unless `become_user` is used in those tasks also explicitly. How do we become another user for a set of tasks/subsequent tasks following a given task in playbook?

**Note:**
I can think of one way of doing this, which is; to refactor out these set of subsequent tasks into a new role and apply that new role on a single task with `become_user` set as desired. Is there any other alternative/simpler way of changing active user for subsequent tasks without putting these tasks into a separate role?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done with the [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) feature, introduced in Ansible 2:

```
- block:
    - task 1
    - task 2
    - task N
  become_user: ...
```